# I want to add more rows to my table on the same page in rails without being brought to a different page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and still trying to deepen my understanding of everything.
I have a table called "record of drying conditions". I want it to show all the records and have a plus sign where the user can click on the plus sign and on the same page they can generate more row as they press on the plus sign. 
I know this question has to be divided into two parts.
First having the user add the rows to the actual table from the index file itself.
Second including the plus sign which i believe is a glyphicon and has to be somehow integrated also in the index file. 
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit broad for SO, but a common gem for generating such forms is cocoon (https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

Comment: @sevenseacat Have you ever used this gem?

Comment: I use it in all of my projects.

Comment: @sevenseacat Thank you for pointing in the right direction :)

Comment: just use form on the index page as using for new or edit and submit it on index page. For second problem just use 

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2